# apk size doesn't make sense in editor log

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Calculation of complete size in Editor is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEQAD.png)

[This is .apk size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vho1D.png)

Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Check [How to ask ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on stack-overflow. It is ill-advised to post images of errors or code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely that the editor is reporting the size before it compress it and makes it an `APK`. From the Android documentation. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html#apk-structure

> An APK file consists of a ZIP archive that contains all the files that comprise your app.

Comment: What this mean is that an APK is an zip archive meaning that the Unity build is compressed to a zip archive which result in a smaller size.